# Green's functions or Green functions

Tags: possessives

In the sciences there exists mathematical functions that are named after the British mathematician George Green.

People refer to them in various ways such as:

Green's function, 
Green's functions,

Green function, 
Green functions.

To me, *Green's functions*, suggests that he (Green) tested and investigated each and every one of these functions one way or the other. Doesn't Green functions sound much better? I.e. that these functions are *related* to work originally done or started by George Green.

For example, here is a little part from the wikipedia page about these functions

> In mathematics, a Green's function is the...

*A Green's function* sounds so wrong to my ears.
How should it be for singular and plural form?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function

Comment: Schrödinger equation, but Mach's principle; both forms get used. It's best to stick with the form most people in your own field use. To do otherwise invites confusion.

Comment: What @mplungian said. It's also worth noting [this Wikipedia page on **"Scientific phenomena named after people"**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_phenomena_named_after_people), from which it can be seen that *usually* the possessive isn't used (but there are some more exotic variations on the possessive, such as [Brownian motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion)).

Comment: And Hamiltonians have even acquired nounal status.

Comment: Here is a related input where the author admits that this is an anomalous case but still suggests that we should keep using _Green's function_ and not _Green function_.

[Green function or green's function? by MCM Wright, Nature.com](http://www.nature.com/nphys/journal/v2/n10/full/nphys411.html)

Comment: I've only ever encountered it as _Green's_. That appears to be established usage. Therefore, since the only people who will be reading it are those who know (and care) what Green's functions are, it doesn't matter whether it sounds good to you or not. It apparently sounds good to your audience, so your judgements should begin to approach their judgement on the matter, perhaps assymptotically. After all, it's the speech community that determines what's proper and what's not, and that's especially true in math, which is all language to start with.

Comment: It used to be Green function, then it changed. Things change you know.

Answer (score 2):

"Green's function" is preferable to "Green function".

For two reasons:

1. Green is also a color, and sounds oddly like an adjective in "Green function".  "The color of this function is green."
2. Worse, every darned thing out there is somehow or other more noble or virtuous because it's somehow "green": green energy; green technology; and so on.  Maybe even green eggs and spam.  Or ham.  So "Green's function" is not made ecologically sound by being "Green function".

Comment: "Green's function" is pretty much universal in English. If you see Green function the author is most probably Russian or German.

Comment: Of course, because Green is a *name*, not an adjective, in both those languages.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that ;-)

Comment: @mgb: My diploma advisor is a native speaker (though in his seventies) from London and uses "Green function".

Comment: @painfulenglish, of course. Just because *I* say Green's is more correct, doesn't mean there's universal agreement.

Comment: Sure. I was merely trying to say that Green function is also used by native speakers.

Comment: Understood @painfulenglish - I was not taking issue.  I appreciate your input!